# Condensing an If Not Statement with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an `If Not` Statement that looks for a certain range.  The one posted is just a faction on what the main one is. How can I condense the code so I only have to change a `Range` in an Array or some sort rather than look for the certain `Range`.

```
Range("A3").Select
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a3")) Then
Range("a153").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a153")) Then
Range("a304").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a304")) Then
Range("a455").Select
End If
 If Not IsEmpty(Range("a455")) Then
Range("a606").Select
End If
 If Not IsEmpty(Range("a606")) Then
Range("a757").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a757")) Then
Range("a908").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a908")) Then
Range("a1059").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1059")) Then
Range("a1210").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1210")) Then
Range("a1361").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1361")) Then
Range("a1512").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1512")) Then
Range("a1663").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1663")) Then
Range("a1814").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1814")) Then
Range("a1965").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a1965")) Then
Range("a2116").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a2116")) Then
Range("a2267").Select
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("a2267")) Then
Range("a2418").Select
End If
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I would like it to be something like:

```
For Each rng In Range
    If Not IsEmpty(Range(i)) Then
Range(i+1).Select
End If
```

I cannot find a suitable way to put all the ranges into an (`Array`?) or collection.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I am trying to implement your answer right now. Sorry someone downvoted you.

Comment: OK. Thanks. If I've misunderstood your requirement please let me know what else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it for the first five cells. You can extend the list:

```
Sub Mukul()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("a3,a153,a304,a455,a606")
        If Len(r) Then
            'do whatever you want with 'r' here.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
Sub Mukul()
    Dim i&, v
    v = Array([a3], [a153], [a304], [a455], [a606])
    For i = 0 To UBound(v)
        If Len(v(i)) Then
            v(i + 1).Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It is currently pasting over stuff that is already there. How can i manipulate it to go to the next range if something is in the cell.  I added `If Not IsEmpty(Len(r)) Then` but it didnt help

Comment: Almost 100% without the `Len(r) = 0`. The one you had before works great, but it pastes on `r-1` instead of `r`. So can i make it paste `r+1`?

Comment: Ahh. I did not notice your pasting at the very end of your code. OK. Hold on a sec.